# evaluating $\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty y^2e^{-x^4} \ dx \ dy$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

evaluating $\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty y^2e^{-x^4} \ dx \ dy$

my book states  $$\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty y^2e^{-x^4} \ dx \ dy = \int_0^\infty \int_0^x y^2e^{-x^4} \ dy \ dx$$

Could someone explain how the domains have changed?

Comment: Try to understand the integral as an iterated integral, then apply Fubini

Comment: HINT: integration domain is the region in the first quadrant above the bisector $x=y$.

Comment: @Aretino are they switching it to the bottom half? thats what I thought originally, but I don't see how that new domain is the bottom half of y = x

Comment: No switch: for a fixed $x$ you have $x\le y<+\infty$, while for a fixed $y$ you have $0\le x\le y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \left( \int_y^\infty \cdots \,dx\right) \,dy$ means $y$ is a positive number, and for any particular value of $y$, $x$ must be bigger than $y$.

$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^x \cdots\,dy\right) \,dx$ means $x$ is a positive number, and for any particular value of $x$, $y$ must be smaller than $x$ but still positive.

They both say $0 < y < x < \infty$.

The second form, $\displaystyle\int_0^x y^2e^{-x^4} \ dy$ is tractable because:

- first you observe that as $y$ goes from $0$ to $x$, the factor $e^{-x^4}$ does not change, so it can be written as $$ e^{-x^4} \int_0^x y^2\,dy,$$ and
- next you observe that evaluation of that remaining integral is trivial, and
- then you're left with a function of $x$ that yields immediately to the subsitution $u = x^4$.

Answer (score 2):

The interchanging of two $\int$ signs is justified using the Fubini theorem. Moreover, notice that
$$(x,y)\in [y,\infty)\times[0,\infty)\iff 0\le y\le x\iff (x,y)\in[0,\infty)\times[0,x]$$
and this explains how the domain has changed.