# How to evaluate this?

Tags: integration

How to evaluate this double integral?
$$\int_0^\infty\left(\int_y^\infty  y^2e^{-x^4}\,\mathrm dx\right)\,\mathrm dy$$
Use substitution or any other method?

Comment: Try switching the order of integration.

Comment: did you mean integral with respect to y first?

Comment: Yes, that's right. That should lead to an easier integral.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty\left(\int_y^\infty y^2e^{-x^4}\,\mathrm dx\right)\,\mathrm dy$=$\int_0^\infty  y^2  \left(\int_y^\infty  e^{-x^4}\,\mathrm dx\right)\,\mathrm dy$

Comment: $$0\le y\le x\le \infty\iff0\le y\le\infty,~y\le x\le\infty\iff0\le x\le\infty,~0\le y\le x$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Well, it does make sense, but its not constructive

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1767257/9464

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty\left(\int_y^\infty  y^2e^{-x^4}\,\mathrm dx\right)\,\mathrm dy = \int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^x  y^2e^{-x^4}\,\mathrm dy\right)\,\mathrm dx \\= \frac{1}{3} \int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-x^4}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{12} \left[ -e^{-x^4} \right]_0^{\infty} = \color{blue}{\frac{1}{12}}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** When $0\leq y<\infty$ and $y\leq x<\infty$ with changing the order of variables we see 
$$\int_0^\infty\left(\int_y^\infty  y^2e^{-x^4} dx\right)dy=\int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^x  y^2e^{-x^4} dy\right)dx$$

Comment: Thanks for edit! $\color{red}\heartsuit$

Comment: =P No problem @MyGlasses